# Поменять местами минимальный и максимальный по абсолютной величине элементы

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms

Ниже представлен код, максимум/минимум находит верно, как поменять местами и вывести  преобразованный массив???

```
private void Calc_B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            int min, max, tmp;
            int count = Source_TB.Lines.Length;
            int[] mas = new int[count];
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
                mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Source_TB.Lines[i]);
            //
            max = Math.Abs(mas[0]);
            min = Math.Abs(mas[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (max < Math.Abs(mas[i]))
                    max = Math.Abs(mas[i]);
                //
                if (min > Math.Abs(mas[i]))
                    min = Math.Abs(mas[i]);
                tmp = min; //замена минимума/максима
                min = max;
                max = tmp;
            }
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) // преобразование массива
            {
                mas[i] = mas[i];
            }
            //
            Dest_TB.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) // вывод массива
            Dest_TB.AppendText(mas[i] + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вы же не меняете местами элементы массива. Вы меняете просто какие-то две переменные. Надо искать не сам максимум и минимум а его номер.

Кроме того вы не можете найти максимум или минимум пока не просмотрите весь массив. Замену нужно делать когда цикл кончится.

```
private void Calc_B_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            int min, max, tmp;
            int count = Source_TB.Lines.Length;
            int[] mas = new int[count];
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
                mas[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Source_TB.Lines[i]);
            //
            max = 0;
            min = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(mas[max]) < Math.Abs(mas[i]))
                    max = i;
                //
                if (Math.Abs(mas[min]) > Math.Abs(mas[i]))
                    min = i;

            }
                tmp = mas[min]; //замена минимума/максима
                mas[min] = mas[max];
                mas[max] = tmp;
            //
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) // преобразование массива
            {
                mas[i] = mas[i];
            }
            //
            Dest_TB.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) // вывод массива
            Dest_TB.AppendText(mas[i] + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Comment: `mas[i] = mas[i];`?

Comment: @tym32167 это к автору вопроса.

Comment: @tym32167, Код всё равно работает как надо

Comment: Но конечно этот кусок надо убрать. Он абсолютно ничего не делает.

Comment: @Orion остерегайтесь бессмысленных участков в коде, они только усложняют чтение кода и не дают никакого профита.

Comment: @tym32167, хорошо, возьму на заметку...